# How to set the dimensions of a tikzpicture for genealogytree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

I created an elaborate tikzpicture using the genealogytree package. However, I cannot possibly center or align the picture, in a figure or otherwise, because the height and width of the picture is tiny, and not dependent on the genealogytree. A quick \fbox test confirms this. This looks like a bug to me? Is there any workaround?

Edit:
Took me a while to prune my tree, and found the culprit is the transform canvas setting:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{genealogytree} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\graphicspath{ {./images/} } 
\gtruselibrary{templates} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{figure} 
\fbox{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=.7}] 
\gtrset{template=database sideways, processing=database,timeflow=right}

\genealogytree{ 
   child{ g{name={Adam}} 
          p{name={Eve}} 
          c{name={Cain}} 
          c{name={Abel}} } 
} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for a complete document that shows your issue? It does not need to be your actual big genealogytree with real names in it, just a small example tree about John Smith that still shows the problem with the dimensions.

Comment: Are you by chance nesting `tikzpicture`s? (It is hard to really answer this question since, as @Marijn is saying, it does not contain enough information.)

Comment: You can edit the example into the question, by using the small `edit` link below the post.

Comment: Ah, should have thought of this myself! Thanks for the reminder. Anyways, I created a workaround for the problem mentioned by using \scalebox. Looks like a bug in tikzpicture, though.